# manually firing the event in c#

Tags: c#

i want to fire an event manually using c#. For instance, say if i want to fire a Form_closing event of Form A from Form B. How to do it ??

After getting some comments. I think i need to explain more on this.

Since my Form A is reference to a .dll which creates a custom taskbar in the desktop,
There is a situation for me to close the that custom taskbar from Form B. 
i already tried FormA.Close() from Form B. when i do this, the .dll is unloaded from the app domain and due to this the space occupied by the custom task bar is blocked.

But that is not the case when i click the close button in  the custom task bar. when i do this the space is freed up.

This is the reason i want to fire the close event of Form A manually from Form B which will solve my issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We did the following in one project:

There was a GlobalNotifier class, which defined events we wanted to use in different modules of the application, like this

```
public static class GlobalNotifier
{

    public static event VoidEventHandler EnvironmentChanged;

    public static void OnEnvironmentChanged()
    {
        if (EnvironmentChanged != null)
        {
            EnvironmentChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

Then, you could raise this event anywhere when you needed to let the rest of the application know that the environment has changed, like this

```
    GlobalNotifier.OnEnvironmentChanged();
```

And also you could subscribe to this event wherever you wanted to be notified about the fact that the environment has changed.

```
    public ReportingService()
    {
        GlobalNotifier.EnvironmentChanged += new VoidEventHandler(GlobalNotifier_EnvironmentChanged);
    }

    void GlobalNotifier_EnvironmentChanged()
    {
        //reset settings
        _reportSettings = null;
    }
```

So, whenever you changed the environment, you raised the event, and everyone who needed to know about that and perform some actions, was notified.
Might be similar to what you need to achieve.

Also, if you need to pass parameters, you can define the event any way you like, basically -

```
    public static event VoidEventHandler<SomeObject, List<OtherObject>> SomethingUpdated;

    public static void OnSomethingUpdated(SomeObject sender, List<OtherObject> associations)
    {
        if (SomethingUpdated != null)
        {
            SomethingUpdated(sender, associations);
        }
    }

    // ...

    MyClass.SomethingUpdated+= new VoidEventHandler<SomeObject, List<OtherObject>>(MyClass_SomethingUpdated);

    // ...

    void MyClass_SomethingUpdated(SomeObject param1, List<OtherObject> param2)
    {
      //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You would call the `OnFormClosing()` method of the Form class. You can do this with any event that has a paired `On...()` method.

Comment: I mean i want to raise the event in Form A from Form B. Say like, providing the below in Form B Form_A.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(------); if this would be correct, tell me how to pass the object and event args to form A

Comment: You can expose the On...() in a public method, but as Joel said, if you want to manually raise the event without actually calling Form.Close(), you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @darkassassin93, given some more explanation for my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Close the form.  That will raise the event.  If you want to raise the event separately from closing the form, you're doing something wrong; move that code to a separate method that you can call from the event and from FormB.

```
FormAInstance.Close()
```

Starting with Visual Studio 2005 (.Net 2.0), forms have automatic default instances.  It sounds like that's what you're using.  You should know that this feature exists mainly for backwards compatibility with VB6.  You're really better off creating and using a new instance of the form.  When you do that, you should just be able to call the `.Close()` method on that instance without it's app domain closing.

If you want to re-use this space,  you might also try simply `.Hide()`-ing the form rather than closing it.

Comment: I mean i want to raise the event in Form A from Form B.
Say like, providing the below in Form B
Form_A.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(------);

if this would be correct, tell me how to pass the object and event args to form A

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, given some more explanation for my scenario.

Comment: Maybe you have your terminology wrong.  It sounds a little like you want to _subscribe_ or _listen_ to the event.  Raising it means something different.

Comment: Okay, read your post again, and I think I know your problem now.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me, from your comments, like you don't want to *raise* one form's event from the other; you just want to *handle* one form's event from the other.

Yes, you can do that.  `FormB` needs to have a reference to `FormA`.  There are several ways you can do this; one easy way is to have a `FormA` type property in your FormB class, like this:

```
public FormA TheOtherForm { get; set; }
```

You set that property to your instance of `FormA`, and then you add the event handler as you've described in the comments.

You don't have to use `FormA` as the type of your property; any form has the `FormClosing` event, so you can just use Form as the type if you want.

Comment: Form_A.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(------); if this would be correct, tell me how to pass the object and event args